# Почему композер с флагом --prefer-dist закачивает все файлы?

Tags: composer

Я читал, что если использовать `install`/`update`/`require` с флагом `--prefer-source` (или это прописать в конфиге в секции `config - preferred-install`), то композер подтягивает все файлы проекта, включая документацию, тесты, примеры и пр. Поэтому на продакшне лучше использовать `--prefer-dist` (например об этом пишут тут https://phptoday.ru/post/5-sovetov-dlya-raboty-s-composer)

Но я где бы не поставил этот флаг, при любой команде или же в конфиге - всегда скачивается весь пакет. Например я пробовал *chillerlan/php-database*. Итог:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С другими библиотеками тоже самое. Я что-то делаю не так? Или я всё понял не так? Или, возможно, некоторые библиотеки скачиваются абсолютно всегда цельным набором?

Что нужно сделать, чтобы скачивать/или устанавливать файлы без лишнего мусора?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При использование параметра `--prefer-dist`(является параметром по умолчанию для стабильных версий), Composer устанавливает пакет из репозитория готовых дистрибутивов пакетов. Этот режим является рекомендуемым для продакшен-окружения, в котором не делают правки в пакетах и важна скорость их установки.

При использование параметра `--prefer-source`, Composer клонирует исходники (если они есть) пакета из VCS-репозитория. Это режим для активной разработки, когда планируется пакет изменять.

---

Если кратко, то при использовании параметра `--prefer-dist`, вы:

- экономите место на диске, т.к. пакет не содержит индекса версий (папка .git) VCS. А также **МОГУТ (но не обязательно, т.к. это зависит от сборки пакета)** отсутствовать папки/файлы, которые не оказывают влияние на правильную работу пакета(доки, тесты, примеры, ...)
- установка проходит быстрее, особенно когда пакет содержит большое кол-во зависимостей

## Пример

**composer.json**

```
{
    "require": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-composer": "*"
    }
}
```

Выполните для него `composer install` c разными флагами `--prefer-dist` и `--prefer-source`. После этого проверьте содержимое папок `vendor/yiisoft/yii2-composer` - они будут сильно отличаться.

Для **этого конкретного** пакета, отличие в содержимом папки с его установкой значительное, а для другого - отличием возможно будет только отсутствие папки с VCS-индексом.

Comment: @СергейМишин  я дополнил свой ответ. Посмотрите пример в нем