# Доработка fork-проекта через git из папки vendor yii2 с удобством?

Tags: php, yii2, git, composer, fork

Не могу понять как люди разрабатывают свои расширения или дорабатывают чужие с удобством.
Надеюсь, что кто-то объяснит.

Сделал форк расширения yii2 на github, поменял зависимости на свои в composer.json, всё работает.
Склонировал форк себе на локалку и вношу в нём изменения, после чего делаю коммит и пуш, а после composer update на сервере. Изменения подтягиваются, всё отлично, но это неудобно.

Я не могу протестить изменения сразу, иногда приходится вносить изменения наугад, так как не до конца понимаю логику чужого проекта.
Аналогично и к своей разработке, если я вынесу что-то на packagist и также захочу работать, бесконечные коммиты, пуши и апдейты?

Пытался найти по этому вопросу информацию, но ничего. Предлагают если только вынести в отдельную папку свою разработку, подключить и работать с ней, а уже после паковать и загружать через composer, когда готово.
Но опять же, а если мне потребуется внести изменения многим позже, доработать какую-то часть, а я уже всё вынес? Опять перемещать в отдельную папку по новой, отключать в composer существующую и так каждый раз? Кажется неудобным.

Пробовал поступать так: есть расширение в папке vendor/name/package/, инициализировал проект git в последней и пуллил, вносил изменения и пушил, но composer видит, что файлы не те, и сносит целиком все в папке, после перекачивает, то есть способ одноразовый до первого composer update. Да и кажется такой способ диковатым.

Просвятите пожалуйста.

И если несложно доп. вопрос:
Есть форк расширения у которого прописаны зависимости в его composer.json. Необходимо было внести правки и в расширения из его зависимостей, то есть сделать форк и их.
То есть в основном composer.json (в корне от yii2) находится только первый пакет, остальные он скачивает из-за зависимостей внутри него.
И загвоздка в том, что composer не видит изменения в зависимых составляющих. Желаемого результата удается добиться только если все зависимости добавить в основной composer.json. Тогда все изменения подхватываются на гите и устанавливаются.
Подключение форков в composer.json как расширения, так и внутри него осуществляю таким образом:

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"require": {
    "name/package": "dev-master"
},
{
    "type": "vcs",
    "url": "https://github.com/name/package"
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Нашел решение здесь - [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/942002/Почему-композер-с-флагом-prefer-dist-закачивает-все-файлы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/942002/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80-%D1%81-%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC-prefer-dist-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B).

Из папки vendor/repo-user/ удалить желаемые расширения.

После установить их заново с командой

```
composer install --prefer-source
```

--prefer-source - установит расширения в "активном" режиме разработки и вместе с ними установятся и папки .git, что позволит разрабатывать прямо из папки vendor. Также данная опция подтягивает файлы, которые скрыты для прода, например, какие-то демо примеры и т.п., если они существуют для этих расширений. После окончания разработки, если эти папки не нужны, можно аналогично удалить и переустановить уже без команды или с командой --prefer-dist.

Возможно, что столкнетесь с проблемой пуша с сервера:

```
git push origin master
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Её можно решить:

1. Перейти в папку с ключами cd ~/.ssh
2. Создать ключ ssh-keygen
3. Получить код публичного ключа ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub (название может отличаться, если меняли его при создании)
4. Скопировать его из консоли
5. Зайти в свой гитхаб https://github.com/settings/ssh
6. Создать новый ключ, добавив скопированные данные

Инструкция взята здесь - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19660744/git-push-permission-denied-public-key